# Clear chat history with a user in Telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

I was looking for some ways to fully clear conversastion contents with a user (Something similar to "Clear chat history" button), but I only seem to find how to clear bot messages

My code at this time:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("KEY", parse_mode=None)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    user_id = str(message.from_user.id)

    chat_id = bot.get_chat(user_id).id

    last_message_id = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Delete me').message_id

    bot.delete_message(chat_id, last_message_id)

bot.infinity_polling()
```